# dynamic xpath expression

Tags: xpath

Good day, colleagues!

Tell me please, how to make a dynamic xpath-parsing:

for example, instead of writing

`$domXPath->query('//*[(@id = "article-id-18")]');`

-> write something like that

`$domXPath->query('//*[(@id = "article-id-*")]');`

, because in my case, the site's script generate (every time) a new id for block, that contains article's text?

So question, is above.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$domXPath->query('//*[starts-with(@id, "article-id-")]');
```

Comment: I've just tested your suggestion, and in all cases gotten only: bool(false);
very strange

Comment: I wrote:
$domNodeList = $domXPath->query('//*[starts-with(@id, "article-id-")]');
echo var_dump($domNodeList);
exit;

Comment: yippee!!! now works fine!)) mega-bomb! Thanks man! It was my mistake))
ps: where I can find more information about domxpath expressions?

Comment: Hi @Ferol, I use this one - http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html